# how to write a function to find max number in a list of type number in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

how to write a function that returns the maximum number from a list of number values, if one exists. In the case it is given the empty list then it cannot return a number.

i get:

```
let rec max_number_list l =
    match l with 
    |[] -> None
    |x::_ -> x
    |x::xs -> max x (max_number_list xs)
```

I got this error "This expression has type number but an expression was expected of type     int"
idk how to take input number list and return output number option.

Comment: Please note that your third pattern `x::xs` is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason for the error you mention. In fact this code (if corrected) could be applied to any list, since `max` works for any OCaml type.

Aside from this, your code has type errors. Here are a couple of them to think about:

1. Your first case returns `None` but your second case returns a value from the input list. If you're expecting a list of numbers this can't work. The types aren't the same.
2. You apply `max` to an element of the list and the return value of a recursive call. Here again, the types don't match. The list elements are numbers, but your function returns an option type.

This looks like an assignment, so I don't want to say any more than this. It might spoil the point of it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest code I can think of:

```
(* int list -> int *)
let max_number_list lst = List.fold_left max min_int lst
```

If you consider the Core library simplest code I can think of:

```
(* int list -> int option *)
let max_number_list lst = List.reduce lst ~f:max
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work if the values of `lst` are negative

Comment: Thanks for the catch @tkocmathla ! I have updated the answer to work when the values of `lst` are negative.

Answer (score 0):

*Here you go:*

```
let test l = 
  match l with
  [] -> failwith "None"
  |h::t ->  let rec helper (seen,rest) =
              match rest with 
              [] -> seen
              |h'::t' -> let seen' = if h' > seen then h' else seen in 
                         let rest' = t'
              in helper (seen',rest')
            in helper (h,t)
```

Explaination:
1. Use "***Failwith***", which can raise exception Failure with the given string. And it won't cause type error. 
2. You can define a ***HELPER*** function, which should be tail recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest the following code :

```
List.fold <mylist> ~init:None ~f:(fun acc x -> if is_none acc then Some x else Some ( max (Option.value acc ~default:0) x));;
```